# It is possible to use SqlBulkCopy to insert information into a view over 2 tables?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am moving to use SqlBulkCopy to deal with large insertions into some databases. This has lead to great performance improvements for one db.

However, another targeted db table is a view composing 2 tables. Applying the single table code leads to "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: View or function 'dbo.vwParameter' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables". It is possible to flatten the view into one table without causing many complications, though undesired because it saves a good bit disk space.

So is it possible to use SqlBulkCopy in this context, and I am just doing something wrong? Or if not, what might be a good work-around that preserves the view for reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that SqlBulkCopy ignored my instead of triggers by default. All I had to do was pass SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers to the SqlBulkCopy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) about updating data in views? There are two possible solutions described there, and the first one is probably the one you want.

Comment: If you are referring to 'INSTEAD OF Triggers' then yes they are already in place. It is used to hash a parameter value and then either foreign key an existing one if the hashed value can be found, or create and reference a new parameter value. This approach works perfectly fine with the current linq2sql individual row insert solution.

Comment: Triggers aren't fired by default when SqlBulkCopy is used. Can you try using SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers. Not sure if it will work. Just and idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view with SqlBulkCopy.
But I believe your problem is that the view that you have is not updatable.
There are certain requirements that view has to meet to be updatable.
You can find more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx
Look for 'Updatable Views' section.

I would suggest you to populate each of those two tables directly, one at a time, if possible?